# Django users created through proxy can't login

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I created a model inheriting from **django.contrib.auth.models.User**, and extended it with more fields, and then created a proxy that overrides **save()** method to hash the password, but users created through this proxy can't login. I traced the process and found that `user.check_password()` always fails, but I don't know the reason.

This is my model and its proxy:

```
class UserExtended(User):
    albums = models.ManyToManyField(Album, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Albums')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("User")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Users")

    def __str__(self):
        return "[{}] {} ({})({}{})".format(self.id, self.email, self.username, self.first_name, self.last_name)

class UserExtendedProxy(UserExtended):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(email=self.email)
            except:
                pass
            else:
                raise Exception('eMail already in use.')

        self.set_password(self.password)
        super(UserExtendedProxy, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        Token.objects.create(user=self)
```

And this is my **ModelBackend**:

```
class EmailBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwars):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(email=username)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        else:
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user

        return None
```

I can see in my database that users created through this proxy actually exist in **django.contrib.auth.models.User** model, so I can't figure out why they can't log in.

Another issue is that superuser created through `python manage.py createsuperuser` doesn't exist for **UserExtendedProxy**.

Comment: what is your `USER_AUTH_MODEL` in settings?

Comment: I don't have one. I have `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['PhotosManagerApp.email_backend.EmailBackend']`

Answer (score 0):

They can't log in because you're messing up their password in your proxy model. This code in your `save()` method will re-hash the hashed password value set in `self.password` such that the original password is clobbered:

```
 self.set_password(self.password)
```

I'm not sure why you are doing that. `set_password` applies a hashing algorithm on a string (plain text password) so that it can be saved to the database. It doesn't make sense to try and run it on an already-hashed password.

If you remove that line the password will not be re-hashed and they should be able to log in.

Comment: If I remove that line, the passwords don't get hashed (I tried it), and I can't log in anyway.

Comment: Then the way you are setting the password when you create the user in the first place is wrong - show us that code.

Comment: When I create the user, I get a well hashed password, it's just that it doesn't work. I  know I am doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what. The code in method `save()` is where I set the password for create and for update. I can see your point, when I update the record I would re hash the password, but I haven't updated any record so far, just created them.

Comment: The code inside `if not self.id:` is where I create the user.

Comment: There is nothing in the code you have posted that shows a User object being created...

Comment: Remember it is the `save()` method of `UserExtededProxy` that inherits from `UserExteded` that inherits from `User`, so this `save()` method should be a creation or update of a User (or how else would it execute `save()` method). I check if `self.id` is null, in which case it is a new User instance, and I check if the email hasn't been used by another user, and I call `super().save()`. This is how User is created.

Comment: Django would never write a plain text password to `self.password`. So the best suggestion I can give you is that there is something in your code that is doing that, which you haven't shown us here.

Comment: When a User is being created, `self.password` contains the plain password provided by the interfase (a form or an end-point). In my case, the new user data comes from a `Django Rest Framework` end-point `POST` request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184547/discussion-between-hugo-luis-villalobos-canto-and-solarissmoke).